# Having trouble using the substitution method.

Tags: calculus, integration

I having trouble evaluating the indefinite integral

[image: 2]

I set u to equal (x^6)+5 so that du=(6x^5)dx. However I am stuck if I should set up the indefinite integral where it becomes (1/u) du since I think that the x^5 will be in the du or will just be (x^5)/u du. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CDwQFjAG&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sosmath.com%2Fcalculus%2Fintegration%2Fsubstitution%2Fsubstitution.html&ei=u9cYVciLGMH38QW2tYJg&usg=AFQjCNGBLayR6PhO9uMEAIi2cGREoOQm9A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in the first line of thought: you can substitute the $x^5 dx$ for $\dfrac{1}{6}du$, leaving you with
$$
 \int \frac{x^5}{x^6+5} \,dx = \frac{1}{6}\int\frac{1}{u} \,du.
$$

This is because, as you said, $du= 6x^5 dx$, and rearranging this you arrive at $\dfrac{1}{6} du = x^5 dx$, and so you can "group" the $x^5 dx$ in your original integral and replace it with $\dfrac{1}{6} du$ as I have done above.

Comment: Ah I totally forgot to divide the 6 to get (1/6)du. Thanks so much.